# How to handle calls to mapping of big structs

Tags: solidity, struct

Good day y'all, i'm tying to write a contract which is supposed to interact with another one that has a big struct that i need to retrieve to do some calculation, the struct have 14 properties and it look like this:

```
mapping(uint256 => Round) public rounds;

struct Round {
    uint256 epoch;
    uint256 startTimestamp;
    uint256 lockTimestamp;
    uint256 closeTimestamp;
    int256 lockPrice;
    int256 closePrice;
    uint256 lockOracleId;
    uint256 closeOracleId;
    uint256 totalAmount;
    uint256 bullAmount;
    uint256 bearAmount;
    uint256 rewardBaseCalAmount;
    uint256 rewardAmount;
    bool oracleCalled;
}
```

Trying to simply get this struct and return the struct throws stack too deep error:

```
function getRound(address contractAddress, uint256 epoch) private view returns (Round memory round) {
 (
      ,,,,,
      round.closePrice,
      ,,
      round.totalAmount,
      round.bullAmount,
      round.bearAmount,
      ,
      round.rewardAmount,
      round.oracleCalled
  ) = IContractInterface(contractAddress).rounds(epoch);
```

I'm not understanding the problem here, i know about the 16 variable limit and i tried to hardcode "contractAddress" and "epoch" to try only retrieving the 14 variables of the struct + 1 variable for the Round struct but still i'm receiving this error

> CompilerError: Stack too deep. Try compiling with `--via-ir` (cli) or the equivalent `viaIR: true` (standard JSON) while enabling the optimizer. Otherwise, try removing local variables. When compiling inline assembly: Variable dataEnd is 2 slot(s) too deep inside the stack. Stack too deep. Try compiling with `--via-ir` (cli) or the equivalent `viaIR: true` (standard JSON) while enabling the optimizer. Otherwise, try removing local variables.

Can you help me out understanding what i'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: https://medium.com/aventus/stack-too-deep-error-in-solidity-5b8861891bae
This is a good explanation on this error, and why it might occur even with less than 16 properties in the struct.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a mapping, a struct and 14 elements in your struct it is not surprising that you have the `stack too deep` error.

The EVM callstack can only handle properly the 16/17 elements.
For instance the `DUP` opcode can only duplicate the 16 first elements of the stack while the `SWAP` opcode can swap from the first through the 17th element.

Possible solutions would be to:

- lighten your variables in your struct.
- split your variables in several structs.
- pack your variables (in your case having 4 epoch times, you could use four  **uint64** that would result in using only 1 memory slot).
- Use internal functions to split the input & output.

There are couples of other solutions.

Here are two useful links that will provide you explanation and possible fixes.

https://soliditydeveloper.com/stacktoodeep

https://medium.com/aventus/stack-too-deep-error-in-solidity-5b8861891bae

(this last one was already provided by ChefAharoni in his comment and is an in depth explanation of the error).

Comment: thanks for your comment, the contract isn't mine and i can't make any changes, i can only wrap something around it

I read the link that you shared and now it's a little clearer how the stack works though i don't think i can avoid it in this case

do you know if i can query the struct, getting back a tuple(14 params), and putting it immediatly inside another struct? somethink like

Round memory round;
round = IContractInterface(contractAddress).rounds(epoch);

This would probably resolve it but i can't do it because of type mismatch between the tucle() and Round
@Torof

Comment: Like I said, get the struct and then process it through a function using one of the provided possible solutions.